# who can tell me how Busybox achieve auto-completion

Tags: linux, shell, autocomplete, busybox

I have read the source code of Busybox for two days, but i can't find the code that achieve auto-completion. 
Is it in file ash.c? I just found that '\t' was treated as ' '. 
Who can tell me which part of codes achieving auto-completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function in `lineedit.c`, `unsigned complete_cmd_dir_file`, is what you're looking for I believe:

https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/libbb/lineedit.c#n778

Comment: You're welcome! Just for reference, I found that function by [grepping for 'complete' in the Busybox git logs](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/log/?qt=grep&q=complete), finding a commit that looked relevant to autocompletion and looking at [the changes made](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/libbb/lineedit.c?id=f128bdbbd7ab14146a45166d20348f7705888353).

Comment: That's great! It is really helpful!